# text getting cut after all values of list are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

On selection of all values in the List(using ctrl+A) the text is getting cut. I need the full text without the truncation. This is [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/729nX/33/). I tried different combinations, just couldn't get why this is happening or fix for it.

HTML Code:

```
<select class="leftList" multiple size="10" >                                                   
    <option value="GPRS_Data333333L">GPRS_L(Bytes)</option>
    <option value="GPRS_&&&&&&&&&&&&&DL">GPRytes)</option>
    <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">GPRS_D_DL(Bytes)</option>
    <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">ol(Bytes)</option>
    <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">G_Volume_DL(Bytes)</option>
    <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">GPRS_Data_Volume_DL(Bytes)</option>
    <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">GPRS_Data_Volume)</option>
    <option value="GPRS_DL">GPRytes)</option> 
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.leftList {
    width: 115px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's possible to help here. This is how browser renders it in this case.

Comment: Is there a work around or a possible fix??

Comment: This seems to be a generic issue when a scroll is added to a List with fixed width..

Comment: The only way to fix it I found is not very nice: `.leftList option {min-width: 200px;}`. http://jsfiddle.net/729nX/43/

Comment: @dfsq...i  actually get the text from a db call ,so no control on the length of text,need to have a scroll

Comment: I know. Take a look at Eran's answer and demo I created based on his idea. This is how you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it allow you to wrap it with a div, you can give the div the "leftList" class:

```
<div class="leftList">
    <select multiple size="10" >                                                    
       <option value="GPRS_Data333333L">GPRS_L(Bytes)</option>
        <option value="GPRS_&&&&&&&&&&&&&DL">GPRytes)</option>
        <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">GPRS_D_DL(Bytes)</option>
        <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">ol(Bytes)</option>
        <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">G_Volume_DL(Bytes)</option>
        <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">GPRS_Data_Volume_DL(Bytes)</option>
           <option value="GPRS_Data_Volume_DL">GPRS_Data_Volume)</option>
            <option value="GPRS_DL">GPRytes)</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

that's way the total width stay 115px and you have a inner scroll for the options.
example: http://jsfiddle.net/729nX/42/

Answer (score 0):

I check the link you provide but there seems no problem when you change max-width property to

```
max-width:215px;
```

Maybe I got the question wrong ?

Comment: This is a part of more complex UI design,so my width really needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have given `max-width`.

Remove `max-width: 115px;` from `.leftList`.

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/729nX/37/)

Comment: Yes, of course `max-width`. But what if OP actually wants it to be `115px`? Why does the browser clips it when you scroll? That's a good question.

Comment: @Hiral..This is a part of more complex UI design,so my width really needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Setting width of option ...

```
option {
    width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLcb7813/

Answer (score 0):

there is a way you can do this... 
You need to change selected text background color or you need to change background color of `<select>`

Jus check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/rut2/729nX/41/

Comment: @rut2..Thanks for the quick response.But in this fiddle only the background color has changed but the text seems to be still clipped